# Multiple Node.js Versions in CircleCI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, circleci

How can I configure my `circle.yml` file to test against multiple Node.js versions?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
---
machine:
  node:
    - 4.0.0
    - 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is unfortunately no built-in way to do this, so using `nvm` would be the only option.

You could do something like this in your `circle.yml`:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 0.12

test:
  override:
    - test that you want to run with v0.12
    - nvm use 4.0; test you want to run with v4
```

Example copied from the response [right here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/different-node-versions-per-directory/1123/2).

Answer (score 1):

Use NVM here is where you can get the package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm

Here is an extract of a tutorial that might help you on your way

Installation
You can read the installation steps on the nvm NPM page. There are only two easy steps for installation and configuration.

Using nvm
If you work with a lot of different Node.js utilities, you know that sometimes you need to quickly switch to other versions of Node.js without hosing your entire machine.  That's where you can use nvm to download, install, and use different versions of Node.js:

```
nvm install 4.0
```

At any given time you can switch to another with use:

```
nvm use 0.12
```

If you want to check out what versions of Node.js are installed on your machine, you can use the ls option:

```
nvm ls

/*
    v0.10.26
    v0.10.36
->  v0.12.7
    v4.2.1
    system
*/
```

If you're done with a version and want it gone, you can do that too:

```
nvm uninstall 0.10
```

nvm has been a lifesaver for me, especially when troubleshooting issues in projects where the user may have more than one Node.js version.  If you're looking to get into Node.js development, one of the first tools you get should be nvm!

Source:https://davidwalsh.name/nvm

Comment: Good answer, I was hoping for a built-in way to do this in CircleCI vs changing the runtime with nvm (I prefer n btw, check it out!), similar to how TravisCI works. I don't really want to kick off multiple test runs manually in my circle.yml file.